# Using Swift reflection to initialize a general class object with data. Cant iterate through properties

Tags: swift, encoding, codable

I have noticed a class where the coding key for a new property was not added to a Codable object. As a result, data was silently getting dropped. I would like for this to never happen again.

The goal is to write a more general unit test for any object that is Codable that does the following.

1. Create an instance of the object with "random" data
2. Encode the object
3. Decode the object and see if it is equal to the original object

Thus far I have tried `Mirror(reflecting: ClassName.self)`. The goal is that I could essentially go through each property and come up for a way to generally initialize it with random data. The problem is its children object is not particularly useful. Its a very weird object that does not even loop like a collection as I have seen in some example code.

Curious then if it is even possible to initialize an object with random data in its fields using Swift reflection. A lot of the example code for doing on this rely on the object being set up properly with Encode/Decode which is an assumption I cannot take.

Comment: Swift has a bunch of reflection metadata, but the official API for interacting with it is still being designed. Until then, there are third party libraries like [Echo](https://github.com/Azoy/Echo) which can probably suite your need.